# Find the number of <td>s in a <tr> without using id or name

Tags: javascript

How do you calculate the number of `<td>` elements in a particular `<tr>`?

I didn't specify id or name to access directly, we have to use the `document.getElementsByTagName` concept.

Comment: you seem to know about the getElementsByTagName. So what exactly is your problem? How does that not work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
var rowIndex = 0; // rowindex, in this case the first row of your table
var table = document.getElementById('mytable'); // table to perform search on
var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowIndex];
var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
var cellCount = cells.length;
alert(cellCount); // will return the number of cells in the row
```

Comment: you could add the check for "table" to support multiple tables.

Answer (score 3):

document.getElementsByTagName returns an array of elements, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
var totals = new Array();

var tbl = document.getElementById('yourTableId');
var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    totals.push(rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
}

...

// total cells in row 1
totals[0];
// in row 2
totals[1];
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

bobince has the correct answer. I tried to give him some love, but I am new with a 0 rep.

tr.cells.length is the quickest way to get what you want.

Now, the assumption is that you already have a reference to the tr. If you don't, at some point you have to have a reference to the table. In the DOM, the table element has an array (actually an HTMLCollection) called rows.

```
table.rows[r].cells[c]
```

will give you the address of any cell where r = the index of the row and c = the index of the cell within that row.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var tot = 0;
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    tot += tds.length;
}
```

At the end, `tot` hold the total number of all td elements "sons" of tr elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
  alert("Number of tds in row '+(i+1)+' is ' + tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td').length);
}
```

will alert the number of <td>s in each <tr> on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library, it should be as simple as this.

```
$("table tr:eq(0) > td").length
```

You can use anything as a selector as you would CSS3

```
$("#mytableid tr").eq(0).children("td").length
```

Would be another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr.cells.length
```

Is an easier way to spell it.