# How to limit a <td> to only three lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I would like to achieve a unified look and feel across all my table rows.
When you look at my example below you can see that the note in the middle goes over 4 lines and thats not so pretty.

[image]

I was hoping to limit all `<td>` to 3 lines.

If there is more to be shown than three lines, then it should cut the content with `... [click for more]` and put the content inside a [collapseable element](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), so that when clicked on it it would show the whole content.

The latter shouldn't be a problem, but how do I limit the content to only three lines? Shall I count the characters to make the decision upon that? Is there a better strategy? I am using Django by the way,but I am happy to use javascript, jquery or any css magic instead to solve this.

**Update:**

The accepted answer is very good. However it comes with a caveat, which isn't easy to solve.
if you have a neighbouring `td` that already goes over three lines, while the current td is only two lines we will get an infinite while loop.

[image]

```
while($(this).innerHeight() / $(this).css('line-height').slice(0,-2) >= 3){ .. }
```

Since `$(this).innerHeight()` can't decrease because of the neighbouring cell holding the height up high.  I think if it was possible to get the css of the current td and copy it across the content completely in a separate field, where neighbouring tds can't interfere, we  would get the optimal solution.

**Update 2:**

As Assad mentioned, the solution is to put a div wrapper around the content of `td` and set the class on the `div` inside the `td` rather than on the `td` itself. It works flawlessly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css

Comment: Counting the characters wont work since you are not using a fixed with font. The "i" is much thinner then the "W". Less characters might easily go over your 3 line requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261368/find-the-number-of-tds-in-a-tr-without-using-id-or-name

Take a look.

Comment: Even if you were using a monospace font, the breakpoints (spaces/hyphens) would ultimately determine the the number of characters that fit in each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you could find all `td` elements that exceed a certain number of lines using:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).innerHeight() / $(this).css('line-height').slice(0,-2) > 3; //more than 3 lines
});
```

You could then apply collapsible elements to these `td` elements.

Here is a demonstration (using paragraphs instead of `td`s): http://jsfiddle.net/jM4ZY/1/

Here is an example of cutting off content to fit 3 lines, then adding a more button: http://jsfiddle.net/jM4ZY/2/

As far as the edit is concerned, this is easily resolved by using an inner wrapper for your content; possibly a `div` element. You can then measure the height of this element, which is independent of the height of neighboring cells.

Comment: Asad, This is a good solution to detect the content over three lines. +1 from me. I have applied it to my app and it highlights the td's over three lines. WIth this in mind I could easily create the collapseable element and place the content inside. Only problem remains how to reliably cut the wording into less than three lines for the header of the collapseable content?

Comment: @Kave Is suppose you could iteratively remove 10 characters at a time and check if the number of lines is 3, and stop when it is. This would be pretty computationally heavy, though.

Comment: @Kave I have added an example

Comment: This is very clever. Thank you. I have applied it now on specified `<td>` with a certain id, so that the computing doesn't end up to run for every td, and hence I think its acceptable.

Comment: there is caveat, that isn't easy to solve. I have updated the question. Maybe you have an idea.

Comment: @Kave Use a div wrapper inside your td. Measure the height of this div, not the td.

Comment: Assad, you are star! It works. Thank you so much for all your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Another jQuery solution is described [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/)

It is described how to change the Text by counting the number of letters in the displayed text. If you are unsure about the number of letters, or want to make it dependent of the text-length you can calculate it by using this snipped

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};
```

which I took from [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

Comment: The width of text is not consistent across lines.